# Lambda that accepts a mutable reference to any type

Tags: c++, lambda, auto

I know that the `auto` keyword can be used to get a lambda function to accept any type. For example, one can do:

```
auto my_lambda = [](auto & anything)
{
   std :: cout << anything << std :: endl;
}
```

And then call `my_lambda(my_int)` just as well as `my_lambda(my_string)`. However, as far as my understanding goes, that lambda *also* accepts const objects. In other words, if I call `my_lambda(3)`, `auto` will be substituted with `const int`, and `my_lambda` will now accept a reference to a `const int`.

Now, I can specify: **I want it const!** by adding the `const` keyword, as follows:

```
auto my_lambda = [](const auto & anything)
{
   std :: cout << anything << std :: endl;
}
```

But I can't seem to find any way to specify: **I want it mutable!** Is there anything to convince a lambda function to accept references to arbitrary types, but only mutable ones?

Comment: What about using type trait `std::is_const` inside or before your lambda?

Comment: `my_lambda(3)` won't compile, only lvalues can be passed.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi: I suspect that OP uses vs which has an extension to bind temporary to non const reference :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a static assertion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
  auto my_lambda
  {
    [](auto & anything)
    {
        static_assert(!::std::is_const_v<::std::remove_reference_t<decltype(anything)>>);
        std :: cout << anything << std :: endl;
    }
  };
  int bar{};
  my_lambda(bar);
  int const foo{};
  my_lambda(foo); // error
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lUa9NPyqt0UGoThm)

Comment: Yes, I was already doing that. :) I was wondering if there was a more compact way of getting that done. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `static_assert` with `std::is_const` to generate a compiler error if a `const` type is provided. For example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    auto my_lambda = [](auto & anything)
    {
        using input_type = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(anything)>;
        static_assert(std::is_const_v<input_type> == false, "Can't pass a const.");
        std::cout << anything << std::endl;
    };

    int i = 5;
    const int j = 10;
    my_lambda(i);
    my_lambda(j); // error: static assertion failed: Can't pass a const.
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was already doing that. :) I was wondering if there was a more compact way of getting that done. Thanks anyway!